# Closed menu after click on submenu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I try to create js function to closed menu after clicking on submenu item. For example: Menu will close after clicking on About me, but it won't work. I think the problem is inside the `'.menu-list>li>a>ul>li>a'`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-list>li>a>ul>li>a').on('click', function(){
        $('.menu').collapse('hide');
    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu menu-content">
            <ul id="menu-list" class="menu-list">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <ul class="subs">
                        <li><a href="#about">About me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Products <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                  <ul class="subs">
                      <li><a href="small-products.html">small-products</a></li>
                      <li><a href="medium-products.html">medium-products</a></li>
                      <li><a href="large-products.html">large-products</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="support.html">Support</a></li>
                <li><a href="#connect">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: you need to use $('.menu').hide() instead of  $('.menu').collapse('hide') as you are not using bootstrap

Comment: Yes but if I use the $('.menu').hide() it will hide permanently. is there any way how to not hide it permanently so I do not need to refresh the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. The `ul` is not nested inside the `a` tag. So in order to make your selector work correctly you need to transform it into this `'.menu-list > li > ul > li > a'`.

But to my understanding the menu must close every time the user clicks on a menu element, so instead you can do this `'.menu-list a'`. Which will select every `a` tag inside your menu.